# Doctrine update entity from another entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have two doctrine entities of the same type and I wish to replace the content of one entities with the content of the other except for the ID that I want to keep.

I do not want to set all properties one by one, I would like a generic way to do it.

Today I am serializing one object and deserializing it into the other, it kind of works but I wonder if there is a better way to do this?

For instance to copy the contents of $object1 to $object2, while keeping the id of $object2 (both are already managed by doctrine) I do:

```
$json = $serializer->serialize($object1, 'json');
$serializer->deserialize($json, Entity::class, 
              'json', array('object_to_populate' => $object2));
```

This is not working so well for referenced properties, anyone has an idea of how to achieve this in a better way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would implement setters an getters in the object like this:

```
/**
 * In $object1 
 * @return array
 */
public function asArray(){
    $properties = [];
    foreach ($this as $name => $value){
        $properties[$name] = $value;
    }
    return $properties;
}

/**
 * in object2
 * @param $array
 */
public function fromArray($array){
    foreach ($array as $name => $value){
        if(!isset($this->$name) || $name == 'id'){
            continue;
        }
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
$object2->fromArray($object1->asArray());
$entityManager->flush();
```